# Sammy.js navigation menu

Tags: client-side, sammy.js, single-page-application

I'm playing around with sammy.js and was trying to build a nice menu for my SPA. My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<nav class="navMain">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/#/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#aroute">A route</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#anotherroute">Anouther route</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <!-- here goes everything I do with sammy -->
</div>
```

For sure what I want to do is to give the `active` class to other menu items on routing to that page. I didn't find any examples for this so far and I came up with this:

```
this.bind('run-route', function() {
  var path = this.params.path;      
  $('.navMain li').removeClass('active').find('a[href*="' + path + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

While working, this doesn't look like a good solution to this very common problem. There must be something more easy and idiomatic I suppose, but I couldn't find anything.

Can anyone point me to a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Update the class in the route handler code, where it knows what route you are on **now** and can just find it on the list.

For this markup:

```
<nav class="navMain">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/aroute/">A route</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/anotherroute/">Anouther route</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function SetActiveLink(name){
    var ul = $('ul')

    ul.children().removeClass('active')

    ul.find('a[href="#/'+name+'/"]').parent().addClass('active')
}

sammyapp.route('get','#/a/', function() {
    SetActiveLink('a')
})

sammyapp.route('get','#/b/', function() {
    SetActiveLink('b')
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! Maybe I don't understand it completely, but where's the benefit to the solution I posted above? This one does look even less DRY and idiomatic?

Comment: Your version looks fine. There only reason I would go for my version is the "Explicit" - line 2 on this list http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/